# Is it possible to initialize a data binding in Angular from HTML rather than JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I mean is, say I have this HTML:

```
<ul ng-controller="ContactsCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
    <div class="email">{{email}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works just fine if I initialize the `contacts` collection from JavaScript:

```
app.controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = [
    { name: 'Dan', email: 'dan@example.com' },
    { name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@example.com' }
  ];
}]);
```

What if, instead, I want to initialize the contents of the collection from the HTML side? Something like:

```
<ul ng-controller="ContactsCtrl" ng-model="contacts">
  <li>
    <div class="name" ng-bind="name">Dan</div>
    <div class="email" ng-bind="email">dan@example.com</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="name" ng-bind="name">Bob</div>
    <div class="email" ng-bind="email">bob@example.com</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then from JavaScript I would have `$scope.contacts` initialized based on what I have in the HTML.

Is this possible?

Comment: there is a way: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit but this is not the angular way! avoid it! Your controller is perfect!

Comment: you make your code untestable!

Answer (score 2):

you can do a `ng-init=""` in your html to initialize a variable or sets of variables but that doesn't seem to be quite what your asking. Why would you want your second example? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Good question! I acknowledge what I'm asking about may clash with the Angular way of doing things, in which case I probably won't do it. But I was still interested in an answer out of curiosity. For context: I am working on migrating an existing app to Angular from a more traditional MVC framework. I was wondering if, rather than do a big refactor where I initialize my data in JavaScript, I could leverage the HTML already being rendered with just a few modifications and get that data "back out" on the JS side.

Comment: You can but you shouldn't. Angular will be much more flexible and less cluttered. Sorry if that's not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: Nope, I'm fine with that answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather use jQuery and parse HTML DOM, if You have at least... 500 records, other way is 'copy and paste' - it will be faster.

Here is short info 'how it works'
[Tutorial](http://exceptionallyexceptionalexceptions.blogspot.com/2011/12/convert-html-form-to-json.html)